# Print Multiple Copies of Record Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that is only one record, however, the user specifies how many times it needs printed, let's say 10. Each time it prints it prints 4 of the same report. Like this, Page 1 x 4, Page 2 x 4, Page 3 x 4, etc. With 10 copes their will be 40 pages altogether.

Update:

I was able to get all the pages I needed based on the values the user inputs. So if there are 10 pallets I have 40 pages of labels, which is correct. Now the control number part that needs to be displayed. It is kind of like a page number but every 4 pages the number needs to increment by 1. I assume I can use `WhilePrinterRecords` and some how increment, but I am still new to Crystal and unfamiliar with it.

```
Example:

Page 1: Control number 1
Page 2: Control number 1
Page 3: Control number 1
Page 4: Control number 1
Page 5: Control number 2
Page 6: Control number 2
Page 7: Control number 2
Page 8: Control number 2
```

This would continue until there is no more pages to print.

Comment: when you preview the report, is it only in one page? is that happens with another documents? Are you exporting the report to excel? Could be a printer driver issue

Comment: It's suppose to be one page.

Comment: is that happening with other documents? are you exporting the report to pdf, excel, etc?

Comment: I'm printing the report and no.

Comment: could you please check if there is any printer associated to that report? go to file -> page setup and check no printer

Comment: Ok there is no printer associated. The report is only one record, that is way it suppose to be. They are actually labels that go on a pallet and each side of the pallet requires four labels, one for each side. Then each label gets incremented by 1 for each pallet. So if there are 10 pallets, there are 4 for pallet 1, 4 for pallet 2, 4 for pallet 3 and so on.

Comment: so right now the report is printing 10 pages but you want 40 instead?

Comment: If I specify the copy amount it will print whatever. Basically each copy yields 4

Comment: lets says that you don't specified amount of copies, so by default it will print one. What is your desire outcome? 1 or 4 copies?

Comment: 4 copies for each pallet, there's a control number on the label that gets incremented by 1 when 4 labels are printed.

Comment: can you just ask them to do the x4 when they enter the number of copies they want?  so instead of 10 they enter 40?

Comment: I wish it was that easy. There is a control number on the label that changes per pallet. So there are 10 pallets, pallet 1 get 4 labels with control number 1, pallet 2 gets 4 labels with control number 2, and so on.

Comment: I added an update, I think the hard part is over. I have just having a hard time figure out an increment value while printing records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want 4 copies for each label, what you could do is create 4 sections on the report with the same info. Make sure that you assign the label size to each page(e.g. 4x6). e.g. if you have that info on your header, create PHa, PHb, PHc and PHd, same for details or PF.

don't know if this could work for you, but at least is a recommendation. You can create suppressed sections with the same info(e.g. 10 sections) and create a parameter that control that suppress condition defaulted in 4. If the user what to print 5, it will enable section 5th, same if want to print 3 it will suppress the 4th.

**Upadte:** how to get the increment:

place a formula on your page footer like below one. It will return value when gets an integer and suppress it when is equal to 0(right click on it, number tab, customize, suppress if 0).

```
if pagenumber = Ceiling(pageNumber,4) then numbervar page := page +1
```

then place another formula on your PF as well like below one and suppress it when `pagenumber = Ceiling(pageNumber,4)` so it won't show when the other has value and put one overlapping the other to get the value in the same place.

```
if {1st formula} <> 0 then numbervar page1 := {1st formula};
page1 + 1
```

**2nd Update:**

Because is a label and your details are acting as a new page do this:

create a new detail section, so you will have details a and b and place your formulas on details b

Comment: I could, but then if I had to make a change to it, I'm making changes to all of those pages. Isn't there a way to loop through and create pages dynamically.

Comment: gotcha. probably there is a way to do it, but don't know how. Sorry

Comment: @BrandonWilson I have updated my answer with another solution. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: I updated the question, if you can take a look at the update.

Comment: where did `{@testpage 2}` come from? Also when it got to page 4 it changed but page 5 it went back to 0

Comment: {@testpage 2} will be your {1st formula}, that was the name I used for test. I have updated my answer

Comment: you have to use 2 formulas: one with if pagenumber = Ceiling(pageNumber,4) then numbervar page := page +1 and a second with if {1st formula} <> 0 then numbervar page1 := {1st formula};
page1 + 1. Follow my instructions and you will get your desire result

Comment: it is not yielding the desired result though. It needs to increment every 5th page and continue to increment. Right now it it increment at the 4th page and on the 5th page goes back to the original number. For some reason this is not working.

Comment: you should be missing any step. Do something, place 2 formulas on your page footer, name them formula1 and formula2, inside formula1 paste this      if pagenumber = Ceiling(pageNumber,4) then numbervar page := page +1 and inside fromula 2 this     if {@formula1} <> 0 then numbervar page1 := {@formula1};
page1 + 1 and let me know the results, one should be showing you the increment and the other 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64419/discussion-between-brandon-wilson-and-cojimarmiami).

Comment: answer updated. If you need future help with crystal report I will be more than glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I have used additional tables for such tricks; these tables must be linked to report to multiply main query results. Some care has to be taken to not allow multiple users printouts to mix.

Example, assuming your report query has some unique id to link and your user/session has also some unique id:

- you create table cr_special(reportid int, userid int, ctlnumber int)
- you design report, linked to this table by reportid and filtered by userid; changing ctlnumber field is taken from your special table
- before printing, you delete all records with reportid/userid combo and insert new ones
- you print report, giving userid as parameter

Say you want to print 10 reports with increasing numbers - then you insert 10 records into your special table with ctlnumber increasing from 1 to 10.

Variation of this solution is to use some other non-related table, like our all-dates-containing dates table :)

Both of these solutions are ugly, but they usually work.

Another approach is to use some stored procedure to return these sequential numbers as records and link your report to such procedure; Crystal Reports and stored procedures do not behave always well however.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case, we were trying to avoid this because of our Oracle license.

Comment: Yet another possibility is just print your report 10 times, supplying sequence number as parameter to report. For our software this would not be easily supported, that is why I didn't suggest that initially.